# MacOS and Swift 3 with CIAffineClamp filter

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I need to use `CIAffineClamp` in order to extend the image and prevent Gaussian Blur from blurring out edges of the image. I have the following code working in Swift 2:

```
let transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")
clampFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
clampFilter.setValue(NSValue(CGAffineTransform: transform), forKey: "inputTransform")
```

In Swift 3 `CGAffineTransformIdentity` was renamed to `CGAffineTransform.identity`. My code compiles however I get the following error message in the console:

```
[CIAffineClamp inputTransfom] is not a valid object.
```

Documentation on Apple's websites states that `inputTransform` parameter on MacOS takes *an `NSAffineTransform` object whose attribute type is `CIAttributeTypeTransform`.* but I'm unsure how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `NSAffineTransform` has an initializer `NSAffineTransform.init(transform:)` which takes `AffineTransform`.

Please try this:

```
let transform = AffineTransform.identity
let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")!
clampFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
clampFilter.setValue(NSAffineTransform(transform: transform), forKey: "inputTransform")
```

Or the last line can be:

```
clampFilter.setValue(transform, forKey: "inputTransform")
```

[NSAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsaffinetransform)

> ### Important
>
> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the
>   `AffineTransform` structure, which bridges to the `NSAffineTransform`
>   class. The `AffineTransform` value type offers the same functionality as
>   the `NSAffineTransform` reference type, and the two can be used
>   interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs.
>   This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string,
>   numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation
>   classes.

Comment: This works just fine, thank you. However when I pass `clampFilter.outputImage` as a source for blurFilter it failes:

`blurFilter.setValue(clampFilter.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)`
`blurFilter.setValue(10, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)`

`guard`
    `let result = blurFilter.outputImage,`
    `let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)`
`else {`
        `return`
    `}`

Comment: @Pono, not sure the new issue is related to this, and codes contained in comments are hard to read. Please start a new thread with describing how _it failes_ more precisely.

Comment: sure - here's the new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942029