# MacOS and Swift 3 - how to pass result from one filter to another

Tags: macos, swift3, nsimage

Expanding question from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941090/macos-and-swift-3-with-ciaffineclamp-filter). I'm not sure how to pass the result from `CIAffineClamp` as a source for `CIGaussianBlur`. The following code builds just fine but does not yield a resulting image.

```
guard
    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur"),
    let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp"),
    let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my-image", withExtension: "png"),
    let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL)
else {
    return
}

let transform = AffineTransform.identity

clampFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputImage")
clampFilter.setValue(NSAffineTransform(transform: transform), forKey: "inputTransform")

blurFilter.setValue(clampFilter.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
blurFilter.setValue(10, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

guard
    let result = blurFilter.outputImage,
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)
else {
    // this guard fails in here
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the same issue with this:

[CIGaussianBlur and CIAffineClamp on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12910625/6541007)

Please try this:

```
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: ciImage.extent)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help. Do you mind sharing your contact details (email/gplus/skype) so I can ask you a few things about this code?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't make any private contacts through public sites. I would try to solve your future Qs, or you would help me in the future. Good luck for you and for your app.